# How can I reset screen data in React Native?

Tags: react-native, reset, stack-navigator

I am trying to reset the screens in my Stack Navigator before the user visits them again to remove previous user selections, but I am having trouble in doing so.

I have tried using `CommonActions`, `StackActions` and `NavigationActions` but run into issues.

Attempt 1:

```
navigation.dispatch(
        StackActions.reset({
          index: 0,
          actions: [
            StackActions.navigate({ routeName: "home" }),
          ],
        })
      );
```

Attempt 2:

```
const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
        index: 0,
        actions: [
          NavigationActions.navigate({
            routeName: "home",
            params: {},
          }),
        ],
      });
navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

Attempt 3:

```
navigation.reset({
         index: 0,
         routes: [
           { name: "home" },
           { name: "selectTags" },
           { name: "selectActivities" }
]})
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try following should work when in current stack home exists:

```js
   navigation.reset({
     routes: [{ name: 'home' }],
   })
```

FYI: Please mark your code as code and please let us know your react-navigation version,